# Transience question for Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let's suppose I have a countable state discrete time MC that is known to be transient, irreducible and reversible with respect to some measure that assigns positive finite mass to each singleton, but is not necessarily a finite measure.  Fix a state $a$ and let $x$ vary.  Is it necessarily true that $P^a(\text{Chain hits x at some time})\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$?  What about $P^x(\text{Chain hits a at some time})$?

Comment: Which examples did you try to solve these?

Comment: @Did I actually tried many things to solve these.  It arose while I was studying Peres-Lyon's "Probability on Trees."  As far as examples go, I tried to imagine $Z^1$ with conductances that are summable, or $Z^3$ with SRW.  The examples suggested that I may want to show that the voltage is a function that vanishes as a function of distance from $a$ as this distance goes to infinity, but this seemed to depend in a nasty way on the structure of the graph.  Also, for some reason I had thought that it'd be important that transient walks always leave every bounded set with probability $>0$.

Comment: Thus look at simpler graphs, for example Z...

Comment: @Did Oh I see what you are saying, thanks.  There are easy counterexamples (for example the asymmetric nearest neighbor walk with any parameter in $(0, 1)$, where the limits in question both don't even exist.)  on p.47 (As numbered in the book) or p.58 in the document here, it appears that Peres and Lyons assert that voltage on such a network vanishes at infinity.  But maybe they didn't mean it that literally, because as you pointed out, there are easy counterexamples on even the integer lattice.  I wonder what they mean by "grounded." http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/book.pdf